# Sequence can have synonym?

Tags: oracle, sequence, synonym

I created first sequence=>

```
SQL> create sequence sq_001;
```

Then synonym for sequence=>

```
SQL> create synonym syn_001 for sq_001;
```

Then I query the user_synonyms =>

```
SQL> select*from user_synonyms where synonym_name = 'SYN_001';

SYNONYM_NAME    TABLE_OWNER     TABLE_NAME      DB_LINK         ORIGIN_CON_ID
--------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- -------------
SYN_001         RAMIN           SQ_001                                      3
```

This is confused me, written table_name but this is sequence(SQ_001) and worked =>

```
TABLE_NAME
---------------
SQ_001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a sequence can have a synonym as you have demonstrated.  The view USER_SYNONYMS is confusing in having a column called TABLE_NAME that can contain other things - it should really be OBJECT_NAME.  Presumably when USER_SYNONYMS was first created only tables could have synonyms.

Comment: And TABLE_OWNER should be OBJECT_OWNER, Thanks for helping Mr. @TonyAndrews.

Comment: I don't think sequences existed when USER_SYNONYMS was first created.